# How does java 9 manage module versions?

Tags: java, modules

I was going through a fantastic talk by Alex and nearly all the things he spoke made sense to me except for the given thing.

[Link](https://youtu.be/rfOjch4p0Po?t=1217)

In a nutshell how does module manage versions. If I have a module v1 with a method with different implementation, a separate module v2 with a same method signature and return but a different implementation, how will the tooling resolve the dependency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't, dependency-resolution is a non-goal for the Java Platform Module System ([source](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/goals-reqs/03#versioning)):

> **Non-requirements**
>
> - Multiple versions — It is not necessary to support more than one version of a module within a single configuration.
> - Version selection — The process of configuring a set of developer modules and JDK modules, in any phase, need not consider more than one
>     version of any particular module.
>
> In other words, we see no need to build yet another
>   dependency-resolution mechanism. Maven, Ivy, and Gradle have all
>   tackled this difficult problem. We should leave it to these and other
>   build tools to discover and select a set of candidate modules for a
>   given library or application; the module system need only validate
>   that the set of modules selected by the build system satisfies each
>   module’s dependences and version constraints.

Comment: the Modules system appears to be largely for the open source community to provide glorified versions of `public`.  This is less a candidate for large Enterprise grade applications as modularity can still be managed using Maven, etc.  Does Modules solve the "when is a String not a String" problem encountered in "classpath hell"?  This is more readily encountered when deploying multiple `ear`s to a server.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t quite come up with proper link explaining this but adding module versioning is a non-goal for project Jigsaw.